# Ordered list doesn't show numbers when elements are using 960gs

Tags: css, 960.gs

I'm using 960gs in my new project, and I noticed, that it somehow disables list numbering. I'm guessing that's because floats. Here's the code:

```
<ol>
                <li class="prefix_1 grid_11">
                    <h2>q</h2>
                    <ul>
                        <li><input type="radio" id="q1a1" value="1" name="question-1"><label for="q1a1">1</label></li>
                        <li><input type="radio" id="q1a2" value="2" name="question-1"><label for="q1a2">2</label></li>
                        <li><input type="radio" id="q1a3" value="3" name="question-1"><label for="q1a3">3</label></li>
                        <li><input type="radio" id="q1a4" value="4" name="question-1"><label for="q1a4">4</label></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="suffix_1 grid_11">
                    <h2>q?</h2>
                    <ul>
                        <li><input type="radio" id="q2a1" value="1" name="question-2"><label for="q2a1">1</label></li>
                        <li><input type="radio" id="q2a2" value="2" name="question-2"><label for="q2a2">2</label></li>
                        <li><input type="radio" id="q2a3" value="3" name="question-2"><label for="q2a3">3</label></li>
                        <li><input type="radio" id="q2a4" value="4" name="question-2"><label for="q2a4">4</label></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
</ol>
```

And in CSS, I put simply

```
ol {
    list-style: decimal inside;
}
```

Comment: Can you show us more from your css, with the floating part? You can post your code here: http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: It's just 960gs, but here: http://jsfiddle.net/pBCEB/1/

Comment: It's from your `display:inline` on the `.grid_1, .grid_2, .grid_3, .grid_4, .grid_5, .grid_6, .grid_7, .grid_8, .grid_9, .grid_10, .grid_11, .grid_12, .grid_13, .grid_14, .grid_15, .grid_16, .grid_17, .grid_18, .grid_19, .grid_20, .grid_21, .grid_22, .grid_23, .grid_24` So get rid of that line and it will work

Comment: I tried adding `display: block !important;` to `ol` but it didn't help. I can't remove that line, it's a part of 960 framework. edit: I removed it just for testing and it doesn't work either.

Comment: Then you can put `display: list-item !important;` , of course not forgetting your `ol { list-style: decimal inside;}`